# Adding a JLabel to a JFrame after making the TextLayout for it

Tags: java, swing

The following code doesn't work (The JLabel doesn't show up on the screen):

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Greetings everyone this is Macklemore");

    Font f = label.getFont();
    String str = label.getText();
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);    

    TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(str, f, frc);

    add(label);
```

While this code does (The JLabel does show up on the screen):

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Greetings everyone this is Macklemore");

    Font f = label.getFont();
    String str = label.getText();
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);    

    add(label);

    TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(str, f, frc);
```

Why is the TextLayout interfering with the 'add(...)'? (This is by the way al going on in a class which extends JFrame). This isn't really important since I got it working anyways but I'm still kinda curious to see what is causing this.

EDIT: The rest of the code looks like this in the situation it doesn't work (this is including the change suggested):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        new Window(800, 400, "Project");
    }

}


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8255319694373975038L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title) {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Greetings everyone this is Macklemore");

        //suggested change
        Font f = new Font(label.getFont().getAttributes());
        String str = label.getText();
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);    

        TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(str, f, frc);

        add(label);

    }
}
```

P.S. I really hate posting code this long but now I do actually need a work-around to this issue.

Comment: We would like to see your code (a [mcve] more specifically). You shouldn't be extending `JFrame` anyway unless you're changing some behavior of it, if you aren't you're better with creating an object...

Comment: seems to be a problem with your container since it works for me. It is not clear which component you add the label to.

Comment: @hairsplitter I'm adding it directly to a JFrame

Comment: use setVisible last (then it works) or layout explicitly after adding new components to your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it all just had to do with the setVisible(true) command. If you don't do this at the end, problems like this start to occur. And while the described behaviour is still weird this question at least had an answer.

Comment: i kind of said that, did i not?

Comment: @hairsplitter Yes, but you only said it **twice**. ;)

Comment: will do better next time. ^^